# Using addChildren() function on my own class derived from QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, derived-class, qtreewidgetitem

Hi all I have created my own class derived from QTreeWidgetItem, mytreewidgetitem. I create a list of them with: QList. I populate it with the append() function. Then I want to add the list to a QTreeWidgetItem with the addChildren() function, but I get compiling error because addChildren() wants a QList variable as input. Is there a workaround (e.g. recasting) to make the addChildren() function work with my derived class?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `QList<QTreeWidgetItem *>`, then appending you can do:

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> list;

mytreewidgetitem *item = new mytreewidgetitem;
list << item;
```

And then, when you fill list, you can push it to `QTreeWidgetItem` by `addChildren(list)`.
You don't cast your item(`mytreewidgetitem`) to qt's item(`QTreeWidgetItem`).

Comment: thank you very much for your fast answer but I found a workaround, so that I don't need to subclass the QTreeWidgetItem class